# Select multiple items from recycler view list delete not working Properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

```
if (RFidList.size() >0){
            for (String s: RFidList){
                RFidTagValueList.remove(s);
            }
        }
        mTimeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        dialog.dismiss();
```

when choose multiple items in recyclerview checkbox not working / and am use               `private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: And what happens when you do this?

Comment: use the above code and today itself i tried and its single selection check box  delete work fine .when choose multiple selection delete not working fine

Comment: Okay, but when you run this, what do you expect to happen, and what exactly happens? Does it delete anything, does it delete everything? Place breakpoint inside this if statement and see what is happening there.

Comment: Select multiple items its delete all the data / some time single selection also delete multiple items and could you help me  private `ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();` use array string list delete item from recyclerview data Exactly need only for the delete function

Comment: post here code of your Adapter class

Comment: Adapter code:
```holder.cbRFIdTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
mContext.startSelection(pos);
mContext.check(v,pos);
}
});```

Comment: Activity click code:
```public void startSelection(int index) {
if (!isActionMode) {
isActionMode = true;
RFidList.add(RFidTagValueList.get(index));
counter++;
position = index;
mTimeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}```

Comment: Activity code:
```public void check(View view, int index) {
if (((CheckBox) view).isChecked()) {
RFidList.add(RFidTagValueList.get(index));
// counter++;
} else {
RFidList.remove(RFidTagValueList.get(index));
//counter--;
}
}```

Answer (score 0):

You can't move and delete from the list. The best option to do this is to have an array that will remember the state of the checkbox. Scrolling through your recycler view will always change the state of the checkbox and maybe won't remember it. The way to do this is to add an array of boolean

```
private boolean[] checkStates;
```

then inside your constructor of the adapter do this.

```
checkStates = new boolean[data.size()];
```

This way you'll create an array of boolean filled with FALSE value the same size your data array is. Now, inside your adapter when you are binding your view do this for the checkbox.

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkStates[position]);
```

Also, don't use `onCheckedChangeListener` on checkbox inside adapter. This will be called even when you scroll and it will change whatever you are doing inside the function. What you can do is override onClick for the checkbox, but there is something tricky here. When you click the checkbox to check it, inside the onClick method the view will have the state as it is already checked so to follow this do it like this:

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Checkbox c = (CheckBox) v;
       checkStates[position] = c.isChecked();
    }
 });
```

I wrote this from my head and maybe there are some mistakes but you'll get the point. The animation of the check state will be handled you just need to handle changes inside the checkStates array.

Now your checkbox will always have the state it had before. After this, you can create a function to delete items from your data.

```
public void removeItems() {
     ArrayList<YOUR-MODEL> items_to_delete = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int i = 0; i < checkStates.length(); ++i) {
        if (checkStates[i]) items_to_delete.add(data.get(i]);
     }
     
     data.removeAll(items_to_delete);
     notifyDataSetChanged();
     checkStates = new boolean[data.size()];
}
```

This works if your data is a type of ArrayList. I think this is the best way to go.